# Where can I find the pricing for SE?

Tags: discussion

I am interested to host a site like SO and its variants.

Where can I find the pricing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SE is not for sale (not any more). They have decided to make it a platform where anyone can suggest a new Stack Exchange site through the specially designed [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com) website.

They have done it this way so that the stackexchange sites can gain the community that is needed for it to be sustainable.

Comment: the platform is open source? thanks.

Comment: No, it's not open source. There are some open source alternatives, but they aren't as complete as Stack Exchange.

Comment: thanks. What is the alternative? Could you tell me?

Comment: @Stack http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2267/stack-overflow-clones